# How can I call a control event in my code?

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

I want to call for example a click event though it needs certain parameter. The definition of a the method is:

```
private void btnSubmitTxn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

How can I call it in an another method???

Thanks,
Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btnSubmitTxn_Click(new object(), new EventArgs())
```

Comment: most of time you haven't used those parameters so sending null or stubs to method is ok

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
btnSubmitTxn_Click(btnSubmitTxn, new EventArgs);
```